# How to get file from Azure Blob Storage to display in the browser using C# api and Angular

Tags: angular, httphandler, memorystream, azure-blob-storage, webapi

My api code returns a file, no problem:

```
[HttpGet("downloadProfilePic")]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadProfilePic()
    {
        try
        {
            var containerName = "profilepics";
            string storageConnection = _config.GetSection("StorageConnectionString").Value;

            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference((await _userService.GetUserGuid().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToString());

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "image/png");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My angular service is not receiving properly:

```
downloadProfilePic(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._url + '/downloadProfilePic');
}
```

The error interceptor is firing and I don't know why:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
  if (err.status === 401) {
    // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    location.reload(true);
  }

  const error = err.error || err.statusText;
  return throwError(error ? error : err);
}))
```

}

Screenshot of error: [image]

What am I doing incorrectly here? I want to display this memoryStream in the browser.

EDIT: removed the errorHandler in angular service code.

Traced call stack back and found this: [image]

Comment: 1) Can you provide all of the relevant deserialized JSON from the error object?
2) Do you have other interceptors that might be throwing an error instead?

Comment: @DanielGimenez 1) I tried JSON.stringify(err) but that only returns same as screenshot. Please advise if there is something else I can do to get the information you are requesting. 2) There is also a JWT interceptor.

Comment: I think you have a confusing situation with the errorHandler and the errorInterceptor. 
The errorHandler must be handling that error before the interceptor and modifying the error returned.  Try to get the JSON from the error object in there, or just take the errorHandler out.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I removed the errorHandler but that had no effect.

Comment: Okay, well there's not enough information to solve the problem.  It seems like something is catching that error and then re-throwing with a poorly constructed string.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I traced the call stack back and found a little more information. Please see screenshot where there is an unexpected token in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to downloadProfilePic in the angular service. If you just use `<img src="<your.api.path.goes.here>"` in your template/html code, your api controller will return the file without the need to go through the angular service.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is a generic error set by HttpErrorResponse when the response code is in a successful range but an error still occurs within the Xhr handler.  While a JSON parse might not be the only cause for this error to be thrown, it is quite likely and why it is the default response.  The Xhr handler tries parsing the response if the responseType was set to 'json', which is the default if no responseType was provided.

Try changing the response type to 'blob' since you're downloading a stream from the service.

```
downloadProfilePic(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${this._url}/downloadProfilePic`, { responseType:'blob' });
}
```